# Android Studio - non-ASCII Carácteres

Tags: android, android-studio

Comprei um projeto para android studio. ao abrir aparece o seguinte erro.

> Error:(14, 0) Your project path contains non-ASCII characters. This will most likely cause the build to fail on Windows. Please move your project to a different directory. See http://b.android.com/95744 for details. This warning can be disabled by using the command line flag -Dcom.android.build.gradle.overridePathCheck=true, or adding the line com.android.build.gradle.overridePathCheck=true' to gradle.properties file in the project directory.

O que devo fazer pra corrigir?

Comment: Coisa básica pra qualquer desenvolvedor: não usar acentuação, evitar espaços no nome dos arquivos, e preferencialmente nem maiúsculas e minúsculas quando se tratar especificamente de _resources_ do projeto ou da aplicação.

Answer (score 9):

O erro está te alertando que no caminho do projeto tem letras fora do ASCII. Provavelmente são letras acentuadas, cedilha, hifens tipográficos, esse tipo de coisa, e que isso gera problemas.

O que você deve fazer?

> Please move your project to a different directory.

Mova/copie seu projeto para um caminho que só contenha letras e números, sem acentos, cedilha, etc. `C:\Temp\Projeto` pode ser uma tentativa.

Comment: Isso resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Ja aconteceu isso comigo.Revise alguns arquivos tenha na pasta de seu projeto,no meu caso achei uma imagem que eu iria por no meu app "testeCópia.png" Exclua ou troque o nome do arquivo e assim estará resolvido